# Eliminar duplicados en base a su fecha

Tags: php, mysql, date

tengo una tabla llamada noarribados,tiene la siguiente estructura,el caso es que tengo varios registros repetidos(varia la fecha y el estatus_bboo) me interesa tener solo tener uno(con el estatus_bboo mas reciente) se que eso es en funcion de la fecha mas reciente,como elimino los duplicados? cabe decir que la base tiene 8 millones de registros(ya use indices para hacer mas rapido el proceso) el formato de fecha es año,mes,dia con horas,minutos y segundos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo que se carga en la base antes mencionada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola sanlegas, lo que compartes es una tabla html que se rellena con datos de PHP, ¿podrías poner la estructura de la tabla en la base de datos? (Incluyendo claves, índices, etc). También sería ideal que compartieses lo que hayas investigado (ya hay varias preguntas en el sitio sobre cómo eliminar duplicados) e intentado y los problemas y dificultades que te estés encontrando, para que podamos saber qué es exactamente lo que buscas (¿eliminar duplicados de la base de datos o solo de la tabla se muestra?). Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir el último o más reciente registro, según fecha, por cada registro, puedes seleccionarlos agrupando su `MAX(fecha)` por registro.

```
SELECT tu_identificador, MAX(fecha) AS ultima_fecha FROM tabla GROUP BY tu_identificador;
```

Luego, para hacer el `DELETE` que requieres, almacenas en memoria la lista de identificadores+ultima_fecha obtenidos, y eliminas de la tabla todos aquellos que no coincidan con ese par. Algo como:

```
DELETE FROM tabla WHERE CONCAT(tu_identificador, ';', fecha) NOT IN ('id1;2018-04-19 23:30:10', 'id2;2018-04-12 15:14:11', 'id3;2018-04-10 03:15:45'); -- y etc.
```

Haciendo esto directamente en Mysql, podría ser algo así (aunque no estoy segura si resulte... especialmente porque puede volverse recursiva, y terminar eliminando todo XDDD):

```
DELETE FROM tabla WHERE (tu_identificador, fecha) NOT IN (SELECT tu_identificador, MAX(fecha) FROM tabla GROUP BY tu_identificador);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando DISTINCT para solo traer registros únicos, en la siguiente tabla observas como tengo varios registros pero algunos repetidos por fechas

```
+------------+-------------+
| fecha      | descripcion |
+------------+-------------+
| 2018-04-18 | hola        |
| 2018-04-18 | holaa       |
| 2018-04-17 | holaa       |
| 2018-04-17 | holaas      |
| 2018-04-16 | holaas      |
+------------+-------------+
```

Uno de los modos y usaré ejemplos para ello es así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fecha FROM ventas;
```

Que me retorna lo siguiente:

```
+------------+
| fecha      |
+------------+
| 2018-04-18 |
| 2018-04-17 |
| 2018-04-16 |
+------------+
```

Si por ejemplo ahora con el ejemplo que te pongo quiero que también me aparezca la columna descripción de cada uno de los tres registros anteriores mi consulta debería quedar así

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fecha), descripcion FROM ventas GROUP BY fecha;
```

Lo que me da como resultado:

```
+------------+-------------+
| fecha      | descripcion |
+------------+-------------+
| 2018-04-16 | holaas      |
| 2018-04-17 | holaa       |
| 2018-04-18 | hola        |
+------------+-------------+
```